# How do I put code examples in .NET XML comments?

Tags: .net, xml, documentation, comments

What tags can I use for putting code examples in .NET `///` XML comments?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try using the `<example>` tag.

```
/// <example>
/// <code>
/// // create the class that does translations
/// GiveHelpTransforms ght = new GiveHelpTransforms();
/// // have it load our XML into the SourceXML property
/// ght.LoadXMLFromFile(
///  "E:\\Inetpub\\wwwroot\\GiveHelp\\GiveHelpDoc.xml");
/// </code>
/// </example>
```

I got the above example from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302121.aspx).

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `<example>` and `<code>` tags.

Check the [Recommended Tags for Documentation Comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ast78ax.aspx).